# Navigation bar resizes when app becomes active

Tags: ios, objective-c, layout, uinavigationbar

I have an issue where I have a custom navigation bar where I have changed the height to a custom value. The issue I am having is when I exit the app, then go back into the app (becomes active again) the navigation bar shifts and resets it's height.

I've tried running the same code I use to change the navigation bar height when the app becomes active but this does not help at all. The code is:

```
[self.navigationBar setBounds:[self getBarHeightAdjustment]];

- (CGRect) getBarHeightAdjustment {
    CGFloat height= 80;
    if ([UIApplication isPhone]) {
        height = 45;
    }
    return CGRectMake(self.navigationBar.bounds.origin.x, self.navigationBar.bounds.origin.y, self.navigationBar.bounds.size.width, height);
}
```

I have 2 screenshots to illustrate my problem.

How the nav bar looks when app is launched:
http://cl.ly/image/473B0v0h143t

How the nav bar looks after pressing home button then going back in: 
http://cl.ly/image/2n012k190r12

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hmm not much activity going on here. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: I'm having the EXACT SAME PROBLEM except it's on iPhone, and it clips the bar appearance from the bottom instead of sliding it up. Weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I could fix this (and i'm not too proud of the fix to be honest but could not fix it any other way) was to fire a notification when the application becomes active, then reset the ui appearance after a delay of 0.1 (yes calling the method directly did not work).

The code is:

```
- (void) setupAppearanceDelayed {
    [self performSelector:@selector(configureForAssetNavigation) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
    [self performSelector:@selector(setupAppearance) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}

- (void) setupAppearance {
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x2a2a2a)];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:kColours_navBarLabelColour];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[self getTitleTextAttributes]];

    if([UIApplication isPad]) {
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:-4 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }
    else {
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:+3 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }

    self.navigationBar.tintColor =UIColorFromRGB(0x2a2a2a);
    self.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}
```

If anyone has a better solution I would love to hear it as this seems like a bit of a hack

Comment: I have the exact same problem except on iPhone w/ iOS 8. This solution worked perfectly for me, and I was able to set the delay for performing the resizing as small as 0.05s.

If anyone figures out a better solution, I would love to know it as well!

Comment: For those that have access to the apple developer forums, I've cross-posted this question: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1065996#1065996